# Set the file name in "SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE"

Tags: mariadb, query, syntax

I am trying to write a query to dump a single LONGBLOB data into a file.

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = 123 
INTO DUMPFILE fileName
```

which `data`, `fileName`, and `id` are the fields in the table.

SQL syntax error near `fileName` occurred when I try to run this query in HeidiSQL 10.2.0.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

The database is MariaDB 5.5.

---

The following query works fine by the way:

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = 123 
INTO DUMPFILE 'data.pdf'
```

Comment: May be you have done a kind of SQL-injection due to the bug of the HeidiSQL. It would be better to post a PR on the HeidiSQL's forum.

Answer (score -1):

Because the `fileName` value is from the database you don't need to put the single quotes around it.

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = 123 
INTO DUMPFILE fileName
```

I'm not sure how filenames with spaces will come out though if you have any. You could always protect against that by using [REPLACE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php) on the filename to either remove them or swap them out with a different character before hand.

Comment: This will not work. Did you try it?